# Exe's compilation on Solaris 11 env using gcc

Tags: gcc, compilation, g++

I am on Solaris 11 environment and gcc-3.4.6 is installed on it. The problem is that I am not able to compile exe's there, The error is

```
-sh: gcc: gcc: cannot execute [Invalid argument]
```

even if I write `gcc` only it gives the same error. Kindly help.

Comment: Is your gcc compiled for your version of Solaris? Where did you get it?

Comment: I have no idea about this, When I got this enviornment gcc was already installed on it. 

Is it like that if gcc is not compiled for my version of solaris it will not work ?? or we have some saperate version of gcc for solaris 11 ?? 

I am new to all these concepts.

Comment: It looks like gcc is _not_ installed _correctly_ there.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike in Solaris 10, on Solaris 11 the GCC is not installed by default. 
Fear not.

By far the easiest is to use IPS to install it using the commands below (while being root or other superuser):

```
  pkg install pkg://solaris/developer/build/gnu-make
  pkg install pkg://solaris/developer/build/make
  pkg install pkg://solaris/developer/gcc-45
  pkg install pkg://solaris/system/header
  pkg install pkg://solaris/developer/build/autoconf
  pkg install pkg://solaris/developer/build/automake-110
```

This will give you all the tools you typically need to build various open source software packages.

Note that some of the packages have a version number in the package name itself, e.g. gcc-45. You may be able to find even later versions in the package repository, for example for Solaris 11.2 Beta you'll find you have a choice of GCC 4.5, 4.7 or 4.8. The same applies to automake which is now also available in v1.11.

(recipe from my posting [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72882/solaris-development-host))

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I found that some include files and packages were missing from my system may b it was incorrectly installed. So now I am trying to install a updated and fresh new Image of Solaris 11 and after that I'll install gcc. Lets hope it starts working .. Fingers crossed  :wink: :)